# It's been called a twitter presidency

Tags: sentence-construction

How can we write the structure "it's been called". I don't understand. 
Written by the Hindu Editorial on Saturday

Comment: It (the presidency) has been called (present perfect passive voice). In the active voice it would be: "Historians/journalists/lawyers/ambassadors  (etc.) have called the last four years "The Twitter presidency".

Comment: It's just an ordinary ***passive*** construction - where the *subject* of the verb ***to call*** (= *to **name**, to **bestow a name** upon*)  is unspecified. Equivalent to *Persons unspecified **have called it** a Twitter presidency*. But actually, I'm sure those "unspecified" people are what I would call the [***Twitterati.***](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/twitterati) (Most Trump supporters don't use Twitter; he himself mainly uses it to wind up his political opponents, who ***do*** use Twitter.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

“It's been called a Twitter presidency”
[*The Times of India*](https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/blogs/toi-editorials/trump-vs-twitter-the-key-issue-is-social-media-accountability/)

**It** (refers to the presidency) ***has been called*** (is written in the [present perfect passive voice](https://www.englishgrammar.org/passive-voice-exercise-present-perfect-tense/)). In the active voice the sentence would be:

“Historians/journalists/lawyers/ambassadors (whoever) **have called** the last four years ‘The Twitter presidency’”.